# Add new Domain Zone in OVH using API

Tags: python, dns, ovh

I want to add a new DNS zone in OVH with Python using the OVH API.

I wrote a script with these steps:

- Create a new cart
- Add a new DNS zone to the cart
- Check the cart content
- Confirm the order
- Check the order status

Did I forget a step or is there an error somewhere? Because when I look in GET orders I don't see new orders and also they don't appear in the GUI.

````
cart = client.post('/order/cart', ovhSubsidiary='PL')

#Get the cart ID
cart_id = cart.get('cartId')

#Set data for the new DNS zone
zone_name = 'testttt.pl' # DNS zone name

#Add the new DNS zone to the cart
result = client.post(f'/order/cart/{cart_id}/dns',
domain=zone_name,
duration="P1Y",
planCode="zone",
pricingMode="default",
quantity=1)

#Check if the operation was successful
if 'itemId' in result:
    print(f'DNS zone {zone_name} was added to the cart.')
else:
    print('Error while adding DNS zone to the cart.')

#Display the cart contents
cart_info = client.get(f'/order/cart/{cart_id}')
print(f'Cart contents:\n{json.dumps(cart_info, indent=4)}')

#Make sure the cart is ready to order
order = client.post(f'/order/cart/{cart_id}/checkout', autoPayWithPreferredPaymentMethod=True)
print(f'Order {order.get("orderId")} has been placed.')

order_id = cart_info['orders'][-1]

#Check the status of the order
order_status = client.get(f'/me/order/{order_id}/status')
print(f'Order {order_id} status: {order_status}')```
````

Answer (score 1):

After creating the cart, and before adding your DNS zone (or any other products) to this cart, you need to *assign* this cart to yourself.

It can be done with [this route](https://api.ovh.com/console/#/order/cart/%7BcartId%7D/assign%7EPOST):

```
# Assign a shopping cart to an loggedin client
POST /order/cart/{cartId}/assign
```

So your script should looks like:

```py
import ovh

# For these 3 keys, refer to the documentation:
# - https://github.com/ovh/python-ovh#use-the-api-on-behalf-of-a-user
# - Generate the keys easily via https://www.ovh.com/auth/api/createToken

client = ovh.Client(
    endpoint='ovh-eu',
    application_key='<app_key>',
    application_secret='<app_secret>',
    consumer_key='<consumer_key>'
)
# Initiate a new cart
cart = client.post(
    '/order/cart',
    ovhSubsidiary='PL'
)
cart_id = cart.get('cartId')

# Assign this cart to the currently logged-in user
assign = client.post(
    f'/order/cart/{cart_id}/assign'
)

zones_to_order = ['domain-1.ovh', 'domain-2.ovh', 'domain-3.ovh']
for domain in zones_to_order:
    # Add a new DNS zone to the cart
    result = client.post(
        f'/order/cart/{ cart_id }/dns',
        duration="P1Y",
        planCode="zone",
        pricingMode="default"
    )
    itemId = result.get("idemId")
    # Configure the DNS zone in the cart
    client.post(
        f'/order/cart/{cart_id}/item/{ itemId }/configuration',
        label="zone",
        value=domain
    )

# Finalyze your order
checkout = client.post(
    f'/order/cart/{cart_id}/checkout'
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it is possible to add an array (e.g. 20) of zones at one time?

Comment: It depends: is to 20 totally different zones ? If some, simply loop over an array. Is it 20 subdomain in the same zone ? If so, wait for the zone to be delivered and then setup these 20 domains in this zone

Comment: The 20 different separate new zones.

Comment: I updated my answer. Simply add a `for` loop that loop over each zones you want to order. Add each zone to the same cart as different items. In the end you'll have 1 cart with 20 items

Comment: Thank you bro! I just run script and it. I just ran the script and it showed that it wanted quantity, so I added quantity=1 and now it just is ovh.exceptions.APIError: You must login first. But i aded credentials (keys)

Comment: Your keys might be wrong. I updated my answer to add a link to the doc. To generate the keys use https://www.ovh.com/auth/api/createToken (ensure to add all the needed routes)
Also check https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/api/first-steps-with-ovh-api/#advanced-usage-pair-ovhcloud-apis-with-an-application_2

Comment: I added /order/cart/* (GET and POST) so i dont know what is wrong. I will try generate a new pairs. Did you had that eror ever?

Comment: Never had this error but it's pretty clear: your 3 keys are not correct, or you are not using the `client` you instanciated

Comment: Ok, now it's ok, except for the payment problem. If adding a zone via the GUI is free, why does it require me to add a payment method via the API?

I added to f'/order/cart/{cart_id}/checkout',
autoPayWithPreferredPaymentMethod=False ( template not found)
or
autoPayWithPreferredPaymentMethod=True (You do not have preferred payment method)

Comment: Never used the auto-pay feature with the API, can't help you with this. Double check the API calls made by the GUI. For instance I spotted a `POST /order/cart/{cart_id}/item/{ itemId }/configuration` with a `label: "template", value: "minimized"` in the calls, maybe that's the one you're missing.